# How to perform a SignOut action in Nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm currently working on porting the following `router.beforeEach` action that I have for a Vue.js application to something workable within Nuxt.js.

I've had a good trawl of the middleware documentation, but I'm not quite sure what the correct pattern would be to follow.

My callback which runs before every route change in my Vue.js application is as:

```
// This callback runs before every route change, including on page load.
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {
  // Reset All State When A User Logs Out:
  if (to.redirectedFrom === '/sign-out') {
    store.dispatch('auth/resetAuthState')
    Vue.prototype.authAPI.cleanseLocalStorage()
  }

  if (to.meta.authenticationRequired) {
    if (!store.getters['auth/activeUserIsAuthenticated']) {
      next({ name: 'signIn' })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

I have the following redirect in my Vue router to perform the redirect action:

```
  ...
  {
    path: '/sign-out',
    name: 'signOut',
    redirect: {
      name: 'signIn'
    },
    meta: {
      ...{
        authenticationRequired: false,
        sitemap: {
          ignoreRoute: true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  ...
```

So on a SignOut redirect, I cleanse local storage and do some further state management inside the Vuex store.

However, I have no idea where to start this with Nuxt.js - any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that using "Nuxt/auth" for handling your authentication. you can read this docs here:
https://auth.nuxtjs.org/

Answer (score 1):

On a Nuxt.js project I worked on, I created a sign-out.vue page and emptied the localstorage from there, then redirected to the homepage.